# Is power-of-two bits per word "convenient"? If it is, why is that?

Tags: hardware, byte, bit

I find several sources claiming that power-of-two bits in a binary word (such as 8-bits per byte) is a "good thing" or "convenient". I find no source pointing out why.

From [What is the history of why bytes are eight bits?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120126/what-is-the-history-of-why-bytes-are-eight-bits) we read in the approved answer:

> Binary computers motivate designers to making sizes powers of two.

Ok, but why? In the same question but in the comment field for the question I find:

> Is the last sentence in jest? A 12-bit byte would be inconvenient
>   because it's not a power of 2. - robjb

Again, void of rationale...

> address calculations are a heck
>   of a lot simpler with powers of 2, and that counts when you're making
>   logic out of raw transistors in little cans - Mike

As bytes are the smallest addressable unit, this does not make much sense. Lots of upvotes on the comment though. Maybe I missed something.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte):

> The de facto standard of eight bits is a convenient power of two
>   permitting the values 0 through 255 for one byte

And this would be convenient because...?

For clarification, this is about the number of **bits** per byte (e.g. 8 or 6, etc), *not* the number of **values** per byte (e.g. 2<sup>8</sup> or 2<sup>6</sup>, etc). Because of the confusion I also point out this is not about Word sizes.

I´m not overly interested in historical reasons. Those have been well explained elsewhere (see links).

---

Related question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606827/why-is-number-of-bits-always-a-power-of-two

Comment: I think that before you can answer that question, you'll have to decide what "byte" means.  Is it the smallest addressable unit of memory?, the smallest unit of data that can be transmitted over some interface?, the size of a character in some String data type?  I cut my teeth on the PDP-10 architecture where all three of those were different sizes.

Comment: @jameslarge Being a C/C++ programmer I think of the byte as the smallest addressable unit of memory. Does that help?

Comment: check the section "Middle Age" in the [top answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/81715/31260), it explains in thorough details why is power-of-two bits considered “convenient”. You might also enjoy reading subsection titled "Building a Turing Machine from Boolean Gates" although it is not as strictly related to your question

Comment: @gnat I disagree that the "Middle Age" section there explains anything about the convenience of power-of-two bits bytes. It's just a walk through of how to build the bare minimum binary NAND gate with transistors, nothing about combining multiple bits into one unit.

Comment: you got to be kidding. As soon as you start combining multiple bits into one unit, everything naturally becomes power of two

Comment: @gnat I'm pretty sure we're talking about the number of bits per byte (i.e. 8 in an 8 bit byte) here, not the number of values a byte can represent (i.e. 2^8 in an 8 bit byte). So if you have, for example, a 6 bit byte, 6 *is not a power of two*, but yes, a 6 bit byte can represent a power of two number of values.

Comment: @8bittree I think I got it, thanks for explaining! (retracted duplicate vote - though I think it would be easier for readers if an explanation like in your last comment would be [edit]ed into the question, this thing seems rather subtle)

Comment: Similar question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1606827/3723423 - the answer brings some plausible arguments about convenience

Comment: @Snowman: The OP's post contains a "begging the question" fallacy: "Why are powers of two considered convenient byte sizes?"  They aren't.  It has nothing to do with powers of two; he misread the sentence in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @RobertHarvey In the answer to "What is the history of why bytes are eight bits?" (also linked in my question) there is the following sentence: "Binary computers motivate designers to making sizes powers of two." Did I misread this too? What do both sources mean in your opinion? Just saying "you got it wrong" is not really doing it for me.

Comment: @andreas: That statement is a bit misleading. It would be more accurate to say that "Computers are designed using powers of two because on-off (two-state) switches are best suited for digital computing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey i think that's a misconception. It's not because binary is more suited to digital but because binary appeared the most cost effective in the early days. There's a very clear and documented statement on that in Norbert Wiener's pioneer book "Cybernetics, or Control and Communication in the Animal and the Machine" in 1948

Comment: @Christophe: That's right.  That's what I said.  It costs less to manufacture two-state switches than it does 10-state switches.  That makes them *more suitable.*

Comment: `As bytes are the smallest addressable unit, this does not make much sense.` -- Bytes are the smallest addressable unit on the memory bus, but you can still bring a byte into processor memory and work with it bit by bit. This is how microprocessors perform routine math operations.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think 8-bit bytes have been successful because they have a width which is a power of two.  If you don't want to address bits individually -- and that's a common feature neither now nor in the past -- having a power of two is of no real practical importance (it's just -- now far more than in the past when sparing some discrete components was important -- a reflex for hardware and software engineers and staying in familiar ground is important for other purposes), and I don't remember having seen mentioned in my history of computing readings(1).  One needed lower cases, that meant something more than the then dominant 6-bit character sets.  ASCII was 7-bit, but ASCII was then though of purely as for inter-exchange (and thus to be translated to internal code for handling), and thus

> The Subcommmitee recognizes that computer manufacturer are unlikely to design computers that use 7-bit codes internally. They are more likely to use 4-bit, 6-bit, and 8-bit codes. There is no widespread need at the present for interchange of more than 128 separate and distinct characters between computers, and between computers and associated input/output equipment. [paper tape, which had a natural frame size of 8 bits but needed parity so the payload of a frame was 7 bits is also cited in favor of 7-bit char for ASCII, power of two is not cited among the advantages of 8 bits]  (2)

and for the hardware 8-bit byte won because it allowed to pack 2 decimal digits in one byte at a time when 75% of the data was numerical and represented in BCD(3).

(1) for instance Blaauw and Brooks, *Computer Architecture*; MacKenzie, *Coded Character Sets, History and Development* have both a discussion on that subject.

(3) Document of X3.2 -- the Subcommitee responsible of ASCII -- cited by MacKenzie.

(3) MacKenzie, again.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is spot on and you brought references. You have my vote. I realize though if what you say is true it is also impossible to prove. Can´t prove the non-existance of something. I guess I should really interogate the ones claiming "convenience" and check their sources. Maybe it is just a wide spread rumor.

Comment: The other convienience factor is that a byte can be represented easly as two hexidecimal values.  Putting two binary coded decimals (BCD) in one byte is more commonly referred to as packed decimal.  This was indeed considered convenient because the decimals can be read as decimal when data is displayed in hex.

Comment: 12 bit bytes can be represented easily as three hexadecimal values. And you can store three BCD numbers in a 12 bit byte. Surely that's a lot better than two hexadecimal values and two BCD numbers. Actually, a 10 bit byte can contain three decimal digits. And I think that's how the IEEE decimal floating point standard works.

Comment: @JimmyJames, I think you get the causality reversed with hexadecimal.  Hexadecimal became popular because it was a compact way to represent 8-bit byte, previously octal was far more popular (and it was more popular on a machine like the PDP-11 which had 8-bit bytes but where 3-bit fields was significant in the instruction set encoding).

Comment: @gnasher729, the 8-bit byte is a child of the 60's. Going from 6-bit char to 12-bit char was unthinkable in the 60's. Even today when we are far less constrained UTF-8 is popular because UTF-16 is deemed too wasteful. A 10-bit byte was about as unthinkable and the 10 bit per 3 decimal digits encoding is also totally unpractical when you are examining values in registers and in memory with a front panel without speaking about the impact on implementation with the technology of the time.

Answer (score 2):

Other than historical accident, there is no particular reason why we should use 8 / 16 / 32 / 64 bit. I suppose that 12 / 24 / 48 / 96 bit would really be more useful.

For handling text, Unicode using a hypothetical UTF-24 would be cheaper than UTF32; hypothetical UTF-12 would store all single and double byte UTF-8 characters in 12 bits, and all triple and quad byte UTF-8 characters in 24 bits (the range would be slightly reduced to 2^20 characters, but that's still four times more than is generously used); code would be simpler because there are only two variants.

For floating point, 48 bit is usually enough. 96 bit is substantially better than 80 bit extended. 24 bit is useful for graphics; much more useful than the 16 bit supported by some graphics cards. 48 bit pointers can handle 256 terabyte.

About the only disadvantage is bit arrays, where a division by 12 is need to calculate byte positions. If that is felt to be important, I'm sure division by 12 can be implemented quite efficiently in hardware.

Comment: Interesting point about UTF, although being slightly off-topic. Floating point byte (or bit) size is an endless battle between memory and precision where you just have to live with one or the other. Good point about bit arrays too.

Comment: Interesting thoughts, but I am not sure this answers the question.

Comment: The question was: "Why is eight bit considered convenient". Surely saying "it's not" answers the question.

Comment: @gnasher729 The question was: "Why is **power of two** bits per byte considered convenient", although your answer seems to apply just as well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43934/discussion-on-answer-by-gnasher729-is-power-of-two-bits-per-word-convenient-i).

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikipedia article for [*word*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)), this makes calculations related to addressing memory significantly easier:

> Different amounts of memory are used to store data values with
>   different degrees of precision. The commonly used sizes are usually a
>   power of two multiple of the unit of address resolution (byte or
>   word). Converting the index of an item in an array into the address of
>   the item then requires only a shift operation rather than a
>   multiplication. In some cases this relationship can also avoid the use
>   of division operations. As a result, most modern computer designs have
>   word sizes (and other operand sizes) that are a power of two times the
>   size of a byte.

Comment: Yes, power of two times the size of a byte. There's no inherent reason why a byte should be eight bits and not nine, twelve or fifteen.

Comment: @gnasher729, much easier to divide by 8 (or 16 or 32 or 64) than it is to divide by 9 or 12 or 15.

Comment: @gnasher729 if word is power-of-2 bits, and power-of-2 bytes, this implies that byte has to be power-of-2 bits

Comment: @vartec The article and quote says "The commonly used sizes are usually a power of two multiple of the unit of address resolution (byte or word)" and "most modern computer designs have word sizes (and other operand sizes) that are a power of two times the size of a byte." I read "word size" is measured in bytes, not bits. There is no rule about word size in bits is or should be powers-of-2 in the article.

Comment: @vartec: IF. Obviously nobody would build a machine with 32 bit words and 12 bit bytes. But nothing speaks against a machine with 48 or 96 bit words and 12 bit bytes. And there have been machines where a word was ten bytes.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Much easier? Any processor with a 64 bit multiplier can divide by 9 or 12 or 15 just as easily as by 8 or 16. And dividing by the bit size is _rare_.

Comment: @gnasher729: division by power of two is just a bit shift. So no, not “just as easily”

Comment: @vartec: It's a shift instruction vs. a multiply instruction. It's just as easy. Once an instruction is available, even if harder to implement,it's just as easy to use as any other instruction.

Answer (score 1):

This is convenient due to common hardware architectures using multiples of 8, e.g. 32-bit and 64-bit architectures. This means greater efficiency when using 8-bit data storage and transmission.

"However, considerations of economy in design strongly push for one size, or a very few sizes related by multiples or fractions (submultiples) to a primary size. That preferred size becomes the word size of the architecture."

[Word (computer architecture)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture))

See also: [What is the history of why bytes are eight bits?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120126/what-is-the-history-of-why-bytes-are-eight-bits?rq=1)

Comment: I will not accept this as an answer. My question is why power-of-two is convenient, not why defacto standard is 8-bit. And the history behind 8-bit mentions 5, 6 and 7 bits being used for real reasons, while going from 7 to 8 is motivated with a "meh, why not". I got the feeling reading different sources power-of-two had more to it than compatibility to current systems. (In reality the 8-bit gave 7-bit character sets parity.) Word is a different thing where I do get the benefit of power-of-two sizes, i.e. shift can be used instead of mult in calculations.

Comment: @Andreas, the eighth bit gave "parity" to ASCII-based telecommunication systems.  But I think a better answer to why eight bits for computer data paths comes from IBM systems, and the mapping between Hollerith card codes to bit-patterns in memory.  (i.e., the character encoding that shall not be named.)

Comment: It's convenient because 1,2,4 and 8 all divide into 8. In the case of 7, that's a prime number and so only 1 and 7 divide into 7.

Comment: @BradThomas "1,2,4 and 8 all divide into 8"? Could you explain the convenience with this property and tell me why 12 would be inconvenient? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Andreas: Power of two is convenient because **on-off switches are easy to build in large quantities.**  That's the *only* reason we use powers of two.  If it had been just as easy to build switches that have 10 states instead of two, we would have built *decimal* computers, not binary ones.

Comment: @RobertHarvey This question isn't about the number of states per switch (i.e. binary vs trinary or more), it's about how many switches to group together. See my edit to the question.

Comment: That is **not what you said.**  You said "I will not accept this as an answer. My question is why power-of-two is convenient, not why defacto standard is 8-bit."  I am telling you why power of two is convenient.  It has nothing whatsoever to do with how many bits are used to represent something, except insofar as you need a certain number of bits to get a particular resolution.

Comment: As to your edit, there's *no meaningful distinction* between number of bits per byte and number of values per byte.  It's two ways of expressing the same thing.  The number of values that a byte can hold follows directly from the number of bits it contains: a byte has 8 bits, and so it can hold values up to `2⁸-1`.

Comment: Logically, it follows that you pick a size for byte that can hold a numerical range that is convenient.  ASCII is 7 bits because that provides for 128 different values, enough to encode both cases of the Roman alphabet, numeric characters, punctuation, control characters and several special characters.  A byte can hold 7 ASCII bits and one parity bit for error checking, for a total of 8 bits, suitable for a teletype.  We've been using that size for a byte ever since.

Comment: If that explanation doesn't satisfy your definition of "convenient," then you need to go focus on something else for awhile.

Comment: @Andreas 12 would not necessarily be wholly inconvenient in itself, but the main reason it is inconvenient in computing today, is because common hardware architectures (16 bit, 32 bit, 64 bit) are not integer multiples of 12. This relates to register size, instruction set and address space. They are integer multiples of 8.

Comment: @RobertHarvey There is a distinction. Values per byte are always powers of 2 (in a binary system), thus it's convenient simply because it's possible and nothing else is. Bits per byte does not have to be a power of 2. The quote in the question claims that powers of 2 bits per byte are more convenient. So what common attributes make 4, 8, or 16 bits per byte more convenient than 6, 7, 9, or 12 bits per byte? You've given specific reasons for 8 bits per byte, but those same reasons apply apply to pretty much everything (e.g. 9 bits allows for parity bit for UTF-8), not just powers of 2 bits.

Comment: `So what common attributes make 4, 8, or 16 bits per byte more convenient than 6, 7, 9, or 12 bits per byte?`  -- 8 bits is the only byte size that I know of.  It is true that 9 bits allows for parity bit for UTF-8, but that's not what the designers of byte went with.  They went with 8 bits for reasons that I've already described in detail.  All other word sizes in common use today are multiples of 8 bits, ***because a byte is 8 bits.***  End of.

Comment: @RobertHarvey [PDP-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-1) used 6 bit bytes, [PDP-10] had bytes between 1-36 bits, [UNIVAC 1100/2200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIVAC_1100/2200_series) had byte sizes as integer fractions of a 36 bit word, [GE-600 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GE-600_series) had 6 and 9 bit bytes.

Comment: @8bittree: All of which were discarded in favor of the 8 bit byte, for reasons which I have already described in detail.  It's pointless to bring up byte sizes that have been irrelevant for the last five decades, when everything after that is built on top of the 8-bit byte.

Comment: @8bittree I think you're missing something right under your nose. You're asking what makes these 8-bit or power-of-two sizes are used, and Robert has shown you many of the historical reasons that contributed to it being accepted as a standard. The standards you've cited are obscure and uncommon (I've never even heard of such devices). 8-bits became popular *because a popular scheme, ASCII, used them* and other standard creators designed their standards around compatibility with something that was popular.

Comment: @RobertHarvey All your arguments are for 8 bit bytes specifically, not power of 2 bit bytes in general. A correct answer to this question (that does not refute the premise) should provide reasoning for why 16 bit bytes and 4 bit bytes (both powers of 2) are more convenient than, say 12 bit bytes (not a power of 2).

Comment: @JeremyKato The devices I mentioned are older (60s-80s era, for the most part), which is probably why you aren't familiar with them. ASCII, is actually a 7 bit encoding (parity is not part of the standard). But for the main part of your comment, no, I'm not missing anything. I understand there are reasons why 8 bits specifically is convenient, what you and Robert Harvey are missing is that the question is asking about powers of 2 bits *in general*, not specifically 8 bits.

Comment: @8bittree (I'm confusing you for OP here and there - my bad for that too) It's convenient to work with and easy to build upon. If I have a 8-bit integer in memory, but I need my integers to be larger, shifting to a 9-bit or 10-bit means everything now either needs to align differently in memory or waste space. If I just double it from 8 to 16, then it's about as easy to manage compared to introducing a new word-size multiple.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I don't believe that the answer has anything to do with 7 data bits plus parity.   I remember the dial-up days:  Parity bits (if we used them at all) were generated by the transmitting UART, and stripped by the receiving UART.  There wasn't any need to store the parity bits in memory.  I say, "If we used them at all" because once the 8-bit computers hit the market, everyone was pretty much using 8-n-1 to send 8-bit data, and let higher-level protocols (XMODEM, Kermit, ...) deal with transmission errors.

Comment: @8bittree: The power of two thing is a red herring.  The number of bits in a byte doesn't have anything to do with 8 being a power of two.

Comment: @8bittree Also there's the convenience of having the standard. It's easier to make a program made for a 32-bit computer backwards-compatible with a 64-bit than having the computer emulate a different type of word-size in memory.

Comment: @8bittree, I guess you have never used a computer where 18-bits was a convenient size for small integer values because you could fit exactly two of them into a single machine word.  Or, used one where 8-bits was awkward because it used only 2/3rds of a 12-bit word.

Comment: @jameslarge: Then come up with your own theory for why we settled on 8 bits, but that's the byte size that we settled on.  Everything after that can be answered with "because that's the size that everyone else uses now, and using any other size now would be really weird and very inconvenient."

Comment: OK, I will:  Four bits is the least number that can hold a decimal digit.  That's why Intel chose 4-bit as the word size for the 4004 microprocessor---a BCD machine, meant for use in pocket calculators.  The 8008 was a more powerful 4004, that cold move two BCD digits with a single instruction.  The byte as we know it was born.  Then followed the 8080, and that was the spark that ignited the whole personal computer industry.  The 8080 inspired the z80 and the 6502, and the 6800, and it was followed by the 8088 and the 8086.  It's been 8-bits/byte ever since.

Comment: @jameslarge: Works for me.  The salient points being: 1. It has nothing to do with powers of two, other than determining the usable range of the resulting "byte," and 2. It's been 8-bits/byte ever since.

Comment: @JeremyKato We're talking about the number of bits per byte here, not the number of bytes per word. Complaining about wasting space in 9 bit bytes compared to 8 bit bytes is a bit odd, considering [most 8 bit byte systems set the eighth bit to 0 for an ASCII character](https://books.google.com/books?id=bXLDwmIJNkUC&pg=PA13&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false), thus wasting space on an 8 bit byte system. But even so, you generally wouldn't switch from storing an 8 bit value to storing a 9 bit value in a single machine, you'd start out with a 9 bit value on a 9 bit byte machine.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The power of two thing *is the entire point of this question.* It's entirely possible that the answer is that the question's premise is incorrect; that is, having a power of two bits per bytes has no effect on convenience. In that case, write that as an answer (or upvote the existing answers that say that) rather than explaining 8 specifically.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I remember that. I think most of the reasoning you had was about 8 bits specifically, rather than addressing the power-of-two thing.

Comment: @8bittreeI I started off with "Powers of two are relevant in computing solely because on-off switches are easier to build than 10 digit dials."  I could have stopped there and had a perfectly valid, complete and correct answer.  The (invalid) premise of the question is that 8 bits was chosen because it was a power of two.  Nobody here stipulates to that, not even you.

Answer (score 0):

Not always are word widths a power of two.  I have recently been doing some coding in a SHArC DSP that has a 32-bit word width for **numbers** but not for the opcodes (which are 48-bits wide).

Probably the reason why word widths are a power of two is because of some instructions that test (or set or clear or toggle) a single bit or shift (or rotate) left or right by a specified number of bits.  There is a bit field in the opcode to specify the location of the single bit or the number of bits to shift.  If the word width is a power of two, this bit field requires log<sub>2</sub>(word_width) bits to cover the whole word.  That is, a word that is 32 bits wide needs a 5-bit field in the opcode for these operations.  If the word was 33 bits wide, it would need 6 otherwise it could not cover the whole word, but that would also be the case if the word was 64 bits wide.

Bits in an opcode are extremely valuable, so they don't usually wanna waste them.  Then it makes sense to make the word a power of 2 wide.

The reason bytes are 8 bits wide is that it's the smallest power of two that can hold an ASCII character (which is 7 bits).

Comment: This is not my area of expertise but it sounds like a valid reason for power of two byte AND word sizes. I imagine you have to worry less about UB too. For a shift 33-bits would require 6-bit opcode, but only about half of the possible values (0-32) have useful meaning. Would you agree?

Comment: the opcode needs to be wider than the bit field needed for the shift count.  a byte is nothing other than a word that is 8 bits.  the reason why computer hardware **tends** to use word sizes that are 8 or 16 or 32 or 64 bits (it's not always the case, the old DSP56000 had 24-bit words) is because of the reasons i gave above and the reason given by vartec: given a bitmap of packed words and you are given a row and column number of a particular pixel, one has to divide the column number by the word width to know which word to access to test or change the pixel. dividing by a power of 2 is easy.

Comment: What is a "bitmap of packed words"? Does HighColor suit that description?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Total lack of imagination. With 9 bit bytes, we would use 36 bit words, 130 million colors instead of 16 million colours in RGBA, RGB666 instead of RGB555 or the monstrosity RGB565 for low-quality color, and everything would be just fine. And ASCII would include 512 characters up to Latin Extended.

Comment: @Andreas, no, i meant two "colors".  totally white or totally black.

Comment: again, @gnasher, from what you write you apparently know little of the history or the hardware.  i was around back then.  i remember text codes before 7-bit ASCII.  i remember UARTs and RS-232 with a start bit, 7 data bits, 1 parity bit, and one stop bit.  and i remember monotone animated "sprites" on a C-64.

Comment: @Andreas: PowerPC has always used six bits for shifts, both in 32 and 64 bits, and in 32 bits all 64 values were meaningful. In a logical shift, count >= 32 produced zero obviously. Shift with carry, count = 32 produced zero and put the highest bit into the carry register. count ≥ 33 set result and carry to zero. And rotate instructions did indeed rotate as often as supposed. For 33 bit registers all shift counts from 0 to 63 would be meaningful.

Comment: @gnasher729 Please don´t insult RGB565. With just a little dithering it looks great ;-)

Comment: *"For 33 bit registers all shift counts from 0 to 63 would be meaningful."* no, there are 30 values that are not meaningful.

Answer (score -1):

It is tightly related to address space. By adding one bit more to your address bus, you can address twice as many memory locations. So when you add that extra line, you might as well use it to its full extend.

This leads to a natural progression of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 et cetera.

On a production technical level it is also easy to repeat the same lithographical pattern. That is, to double it. If you start out with one latch and then double the pattern, you will pass 8, not 6, 10 or 12.

Comment: How is that related to the number of bits in a byte? Are you seriously claiming that a 32 bit logical AND is easier to implement than 36 or 28 bits?

Comment: I did not make any such claim. My suggestion is it stems from earlier designs that were progressively extended in widrh as transistors got cheaper and ICs allowed for smaller circuits.

Comment: Interesting theory about production technical level. You might be on to something. Could you extend the paragraph or maybe provide a link explaining the basics?

Comment: It's nonsense. For example, in a graphics card where all kinds of odd bit sizes are needed in various places, everything is done exactly with the required size, and not one bit more. If an h.264 decoder needs 19 bits precision for some operation, then the hardware implements 19 bits and not 20 or 24 or 32. And excuse me, you don't manipulate lithographical patterns. You define the hardware and then run it through some software that creates the layout.

Comment: Intel's first microprocessor (that was widely accepted as such) was the 4004 and it had a 4-bit architecture. I think they were used for desk calculators. From that came the 8008 which was 8-bit. And another bunch of 8-bits until the first 16-bit incarnation. So I imagine the roots of the microprocessor having something to do with the 8-bit central architecture that is still used. Mass production issues and the need for backward compatibility have always been important, making doubling beneficial. I am making this up but I think it makes sense.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_4004

Comment: @gnasher  GPU manufacturers have their own backyards to work in, backward compatibility is not an issue to them. I am pretty sure compatibility was a driving factor for doubling the width of data busses with each new generation, which makes you stick to the 8-bit base. Production technical it may not have been such an issue, I may have been overspeculating there.

Comment: @MartinMaat: You are confusing marketing + standardisation with technological reasons. And technology is what we are discussing.